# Angular11 chip prevent user from inputing wrong values

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11

I want to implement the "chips component" of angular materials. I wanted to use the [chip material with autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples) but i would like to make sure that the value used exists in a given list before adding it.

For example in the link provided you only got a list of fruits. How to prevent a user from entering "concrete" into the list (which is not a part of our fruit list here ?)

I don't want the verification to be in a "save" button or something, I want to avoid the input of wrong values from the beginning.

Here is a [stackblitz from angular without the input verification](https://stackblitz.com/angular/krvavrnaneq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts)

Many thanks !
Kev'.

Comment: I would advise adding your code here otherwise some people may start downvoting your question and it doesn't help either you or anyother person that may benefit from your question.

Comment: Hey there. I have no code.. this is a theorical question I am asking for a way to do. But I've added the stackblitz example from angular in my post. Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the add function, which receives the newly added value, check on the list, for this example the "fruits" whether the current value existed or not.

[image]

Comment: Ho yea did not thinkg about that at all.. thx !